# How to make v-for :key unique?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, key, uuid, v-for

I am having issues with items not properly adding/deleting from array, and I know it is because I need to be using something unique for my `:key` property. My app renders with a grid-item labeled `Step:0`, if I create a `Step 1` and `Step 2`, and then I delete `Step 1`, and add another step, then both the step 1 and new step 2 drag with each other at the same time.

Currently my key is `index` for troubleshooting purposes, but I want my key to be `step.uuid` I have added a library with the function `uuidv1()` which generates a random number/letter string, I want `step.uuid` to receive these keys and store them as the value, but I am not sure how to do this properly as I am a JS noob.

```html
<grid-layout>
  <grid-item
    v-for="(step, index) in stepsGrid"
    v-bind:index="index"
    v-bind:key="index"
    :x="step.x"
    :y="step.y"
    :w="step.w"
    :h="step.h"
    :i="step.i"
    :uuid="step.uuid"
    :isDraggable="step.isDraggable"
  >
    <div class="Panel__name">
      Step: {{index}}
      <div class="Panel__stepcount">
        Loop Count:
        <input type="number" value="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editButton">
      <router-link to="/Parameters-template" class="editButton">Edit</router-link>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="Panel__status">Status:</div>
    <div class="trashcan" @click="removeStep(step)">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="color:#f6a821;"></i>
    </div>
  </grid-item>
</grid-layout>
```

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: {
    stepsGrid: [{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1, i: 0, uuid: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' }],
    actions: {
      removeElement(step) {
        if (step == this.selectedItem) {
          this.selectElement(null)
        }
      },
      onClickaddStep({ state, commit }) {
        const step = {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
          w: 2,
          h: 1,
          i: String(state.stepsGrid.length),
        }
        commit('onClickaddStep', step)
      },

      uuidv1() {
        const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')
        uuid.v1()
        // console.log(uuid.v1());
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Every time I create a new item, I need the `uuidv1` to create a new random number and store it in the next row for `step.uuid`. I am beginning to frustrate myself, because I know how simple it is, I just can't seem to find the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should `require` `uuid` at the top of the script. Then you should invoke that function when you init your initial state and every time when you add new step. Take a look at this code snippet:

```js
const uuid = require('uuid/v1')

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  state: {
    // // get unique id when init initial state
    stepsGrid: [{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1, i: 0, uuid: uuid() }],
    actions: {
      onClickaddStep({ state, commit }) {
        const step = {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
          w: 2,
          h: 1,
          i: String(state.stepsGrid.length),
          // get unique id when adding new step
          uuid: uuid()
        }
        commit('onClickaddStep', step)
      },
    },
  },
  ...
})
```

After that **don't forget** to bind `:key` to `step.uuid` value in your `template`:
`<grid-item v-for="(step, index) in stepsGrid" :key="step.uuid">`.

Comment: I have been trying this, I get the error: ReferenceError: uuid is not defined
    at eval (store.js?8809:21)
    at Module../src/renderer/store/store.js

Comment: If you want, I just uploaded a copy of my project to GitHub for a friend who is trying to go through it and help me out: https://github.com/julianstogs/ald---copy-for-collin